# How to set custom cookies in Wordpress after a form is filled on a page

Tags: page-template, forms, cookies

I have built a custom template for page in Wordpress: page-xyz.php

This page has a some content. I want to check cookie. What I want to do is:

If cookie is set:

//show page content

else

//don't show the content. Instead show this form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

After this form is submitted:

1. cookie must be set
2. do some mysql query
3. show the content

I have tried but no success so far.

Comment: Have you read the [WordPress Cookies](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies) Codex page?

Comment: @CharlesClarkson and why do you think this Codex page is important in this case? Amit wants to set custom cookie, so WordPress standard auth cookie isn't very helpful here, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Your `page-xyz.php` has to look like this:

```
$cookie_set = isset( $_COOKIE['mycookie'] );

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) :
    // exec your mysql queries and do else stuff...

    // after it set your cookie
    setcookie('mycookie', 'some value');
    $cookie_set = true;
endif;

if ( $cookie_set ) :
    // render your content here
else :
    // render your form here
endif;
```